# Can a WCF Service provide publish/subscribe activity to a Linux-based C++ client application?

Tags: linux, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service written to provide certain functionality to intranet-based clients.  This is easy when a client is running Windows.  I want to implement the same functionality for my Windows clients that is available to my linux clients.  My questions are?

How can I communicate to a linux c++ based client (supporting callback operations for a publish subscribe) type situation?  I am aware of using SOAP over the HTTPBinding but is that the only way (does not support callbacks I believe)?

Would the same apply if I were using TCPBinding on the service-side?  Currently, the service is set up using TCP but what are my options for the linux client communcation?

I read somewhere that messages can also be sent (via webservices I believe) in XML rather than SOAP?  Which would be a better approach or how to determine which is a better approach?

I am trying to understand the options I would have for a WCF data service if I wanted to communicate with it from a linux client.  I appreciate all your help.

Thank You,

Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

On the linux side Mono is developing WCF functionality but it is not finished yet

http://go-mono.com/status/

On the c side there is a WCF template, but I think that it only supports basicHttpBinding

http://www.blinnov.com/2008/01/22/wcf-service-unmanaged-client/en/